# Apache ECharts: Rotated labels get cropped

Tags: echarts

I'm trying to use rotated labels in my graph. However, the labels are getting cropped. How can I make more space in the bottom so that the labels can fit?

[image]

```
  options = {
    xAxis: {
      type: "category",
      data: axis,
      axisLabel: {
        show: true,
        interval: 0,
        rotate: 45,
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: true,
        interval: 0
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: "value",
      data: axis,
      min: 1,
      minInterval: 1,
      maxInterval: 1,
      max: 15,
      axisTick: {
        interval: 1
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        stack: "minmax",
        itemStyle: {
          normal: {
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
          }
        },
        data: maxs
      },
      {
        type: "bar",
        stack: "minmax",
        data: mins,
        itemStyle: { color: "#63869e" }
      },
      {
        symbolSize: 20,
        data: scatter,
        type: "scatter",
        itemStyle: { color: "black" },
      },
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space can be added with grid option [bottom](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid.bottom):

```js
options = {
  grid: {
    bottom: 100,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To contain the label you can use:

```js
options = {
  grid: {
    containLabel: true,
  }
}
```